# Split a string that I read from a file

Tags: c, arrays, file

I have a file like this

```
GET /index.html k
GET /docencia.html k
GET /ejemplo.html k
```

and I want to read it line by line and split it up with this delimiter `" "` but is giving me this error: `segmentation fault(core dumped)` and I don't know what to try.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char ordenes[150];
    char *orden[3];
    char *token;
    int tok;

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File error");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (feof(fp) == 0) {
        fgets(ordenes, sizeof(ordenes), fp);
        printf("%s \n", ordenes);
        token = strtok(ordenes, " ");
        tok = 0;
        while (token != NULL) {
            orden[tok] = strdup(token);
            tok++;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }

        printf("\n%s\n", orden[0]);
        printf("\n%s\n", orden[1]);
        printf("\n%s\n", orden[2]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

The error shows when I call the first `strdup`. If I try to print the token just after I call the first `strtok`, it fails too (the same `segmentation fault core dumped`) so I guess the problem is with the `strtok`.

Comment: `token = strtok(NULL," ");` move to loop-end. or `if(token)break;` after `token = strtok(NULL," ");`.

Comment: put `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: Okay the include was the problem... The compiler didnt show anything so i thought with the std was good.

Comment: Please read ["why is `while(!feof())` always wrong"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not include `<string.h>`, so the compiler applies the default argument promotions on the signature of strtok, in particular it considers that strtok returns an `int`.

So the compiler will apply an operator of coercion from `int` to `pointer to char` at the assignment

```
token = strtok(ordenes, " ");
```

and this assignment will be compiled as

```
token = (int->char*) strtok(ordenes, " ");
```

Comment: Good catch! This will definitely cause problems on 64-bit systems, while is might go unnoticed on 32-bit ones.  Definitely undefined behavior! You could also advise the OP to use compiler warnings to avoid such silly mistakes. `gcc -Wall -W`, `clang -Weverything`...

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- As alinsoar diagnosed with a sharp eye, you do not include `<string.h>`. `strtok` is not defined, the compiler must assume it returns an `int`, which it does not, and this `int` is silently converted to a `char *`.  The code generated invokes undefined behavior and will most likely crash on 64-bit targets.  You should compile with all warnings enabled to let the compiler help avoid this kind of silly mistake. `gcc -Wall -W` or `clang -Weverything`...
- You do not check if command line arguments have been passed to your program before calling `fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");`. If no arguments are passed, `argv[1]` is a null pointer.
- `while (feof(fp) == 0)` is incorrect, read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) . You should instead write `while (fgets(ordenes, sizeof(ordenes), fp)) {...`
- You do not check if `tok < 3` before storing `token` into the `orden` array.  If the line has more than 3 fields, you will cause a buffer overflow.
- You do not check if 3 tokens were indeed found before printing all 3 entries in `orden`. This too might invoke undefined behavior, especially if `fgets()` failed to read a line, which you do not check.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char ordenes[150];
    char *orden[3];
    char *token;
    int i, tok;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Missing command line argument\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open input file %s: %s\n", 
                argv[1], strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(ordenes, sizeof(ordenes), fp)) {
        printf("%s", ordenes);
        token = strtok(ordenes, " ");
        for (tok = 0; tok < 3 && token != NULL; tok++) {
            orden[tok] = strdup(token);
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        for (i = 0; i < tok; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", orden[i]);
            free(orden[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your answer did help a lot, because i realized that the loop was iterating one more time that expected

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void play_with_token(char *token, char const *delim)
{
  if (token == NULL)
    return;
  printf(" %s", token);
  play_with_token(strtok(NULL, delim), delim);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
      return 1;
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
      return 1;

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
      printf("parsing line :");
      char const *delim = " ";
      play_with_token(strtok(line, delim), delim);
      printf("\n");
    }
   free(line);
   fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Your tail recursion style in `play_with_token` is not idiomatic in C. It is especially bad style as the initial and subsequent calls to `strtok()` appear in different functions.  `strtok()` semantics and non reentrancy issues are enough of an issue to make it highly advisable to keep all calls close together.

Comment: @chqrlie It's a style issue, I don't think that is bad because `play_with_token()` don't need to know the real string. I will just add delim to be more logic.

Comment: It may be a style issue, but how would you rate a purposely obfuscated answer? Making `play_with_token` local and `static` does not fix the poor pedagogical value of this approach.  You are probably well aware of the shortcomings of `strtok()`, but most newbie reader aren't.

Comment: I think that it is not the purpose to display the actual  OP. Process the file of the second item, for example. Your method is not suitable.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY "I want to read it line by line and split it up with this delimiter " "", I just answer literally what he asks.

Comment: Yes, but it is scarce in actual use.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY My answer can be used by everyone, and I answer the OP. A lot of people; maybe don't care about what the OP wants to do with that. The OP didn't ask "... and how to stock it in?".

Comment: Dare to say, you reorganized without consent. That is what He/She did not need to ask.

Comment: @Stargateur: the tail recursion is not so much of an issue as the fact that you call `strtok(NULL, " ")` in `play_with_token()` assuming that `strtok(line, " ")` was called by the caller.  This is what I find misleading for newbies. If you were to use the safer `strtok_r()` version, your approach would become more cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you should change the condition in the outer loop statement the following way

```
while ( fgets(ordenes, sizeof(ordenes), fp) != NULL )
```

The condition in the inner loop should be written at least like

```
  while ( tok < 3 && token != NULL) {
```

The tokens should be outputted in a loop and the allocated memory must be freed. For example

```
  for ( int i = 0; i < tok; i++ )
  {
      printf("\n%s\n", orden[i]);
      free( orden[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char ordenes[150];
    char *orden[3];
    char *token;
    int tok;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("File error");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(fgets(ordenes, sizeof(ordenes), fp)){
        printf("%s\n",ordenes);
        token = strtok(ordenes, " ");
        tok = 0;
        while (token != NULL){
            orden[tok++] = strdup(token);
            token = strtok(NULL," ");
        }
        printf("\n%s\n",orden[0]);
        printf("\n%s\n",orden[1]);
        printf("\n%s\n",orden[2]);
        free(orden[0]);free(orden[1]);free(orden[2]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: You have undefined behavior, `tok++` what if it's go over 2? `argv[1]` what if it's `NULL`? You didn't set orden elem to `NULL`, so `free` or use them is UB.

Comment: Assuming correct input format leads to undefined behavior and exploitable flaws.